# transfer of data from webpage to a server c program

Tags: javascript, html, c

i have a javascript page which displays 1,2,3,4 for up down left and right arrow.

i have a c server program listening on port 5000 and running in web server.

which is most efficient and possible ways transfer this data 1,2,3,4 acc to user pressing the keyboard and data receiving at server side.

few methods i have seen is
1. html page - php - C server
2. html - cgi script- C server
3. java server pages - java server program- java client- C server.
4. html page - servlets - c program.

pls suggest any better methods or how to really implement the above said methods

Answer (score 1):

If you have a PHP script on the server then you don't need a "C" server (I'm assuming you mean a cgi program written in C). Looks to me like PHP + JavaScript (AJAX) is the best option for you.

You may want to read this 30 minute AJAX tutorial by Rasmus Lerdorf http://marc.info/?l=php-general&m=112198633625636&w=2