# Send data from local webpage to C program running locally

Tags: c, windows, web, cross-platform, ipc

I'm looking for the simplest possible (cross-platform, but not necessarily cross-browser) code to **send** data from a local web page to a C (*not* C++) application running locally. Basically, I have an HTML page with a form and I want to send the data from that form to another process in the simplest way possible. (I know that I can read local data from a webpage relatively easily, especially now with HTML5, but writing outside of the javascript sandbox is a mystery.)

I know that browsers make this very hard to do for security concerns, and I don't want to open  up my machine to attacks, but maybe I can run a very simple server inside the C application to receive the submitted data... Either way, I cannot run any standard webserver, so I need to have a C library/app that does it for me.

I've looked into .hta files (seem to only work for Windows) and some C web servers (all I've found are *nix specific). A similar question is how to [transfer of data from webpage to a server c program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826345/transfer-of-data-from-webpage-to-a-server-c-program) , except that user allows the use of Java and other webserver platforms (I must use C).

UPDATE: Promising libraries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175507/c-c-web-server-library

Comment: Hi Pat.  I need more information.  What is your web page written in? PHP? or something even simpler?

Comment: Simpler, just HTML and javascript. If it were using PHP (or any other web language), I'd need a (more) complex web server.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered FastCGI?  I have a fast CGI library written in C that might be helpful.  It still needs a lot of work and I'm not sure if I would want to use in a production environment.

If you find any bugs or make any enhancements, please share them so that it can help others.

https://github.com/manvscode/shrewd-cgi

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but doesn't (Fast)CGI require a web server? Because I don't have one of those. But I'm looking into embedding Mongoose (a small, cross-platform C web server) into my C app as a possible solution (I'll post here if I get it to work).

Answer (score 0):

You could write a *very simple* web server in C, serve the page from it (avoids security issues), and post the form to it.

Comment: Maybe *you* can write a very simple web server in C, but my motivation for asking the question was also for some guidance.

Comment: I think you overestimate what it would take.  Depending on your needs, you could skip a whole lot of stuff.  If you can do socket programming, think in terms of 1) listen for connections on 127.0.0.1:80 (so nothing outside can connect) 2) accept connection and read the data 3a) if it starts with GET, send a 200 OK and the HTML page and close the socket.  3b) if it starts with POST, skip to the first blank line then read you form data, then send the 200 OK and HTML page and close the socket.  You'll have a few HTTP headers to send back, but really, there are plenty of examples around.

Answer (score 0):

If you're bound to c, you'll have to go low-level and deal with all the nifty details around the *sockets* library. (There's a reason why people abstract that in high-level languages). Check out some example code for RPC in C with server and client [here](http://www.pcs.cnu.edu/~dgame/sockets/sockets.html). If you can afford to bind to C, e.g. using Tcl, i would implement the server in a tcl script and bind your C functions as a Tcl command. That way you pass the content directly to your c method while avoiding to write all the sockets code low-level.

Comment: As far as I know, it's difficult to do cross-platform socket programming in C (http://stackoverflow.com/a/169147/116891). If there are libraries that already do it, I'd rather use them :-)

Comment: Most of them are C++, like ACE, but if you're only concerned about Unix, Windows and OSX you can try porting your stuff on windows by using cygwin.

Comment: I'm looking into https://github.com/valenok/mongoose (cross-platform, C) at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

Send the desired data from web to specific port of your system (for example port X). Then run your application (e.g. APP) in background using following command:

```
nc -l X | ./APP
```

And of course you need [nc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) package.

Comment: It also seems that *nix is a prerequisite, so that won't work. Thus the 'cross-platform' and 'windows' tags on the question.